# DataContext not released with Command Binding in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, memory, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps

I have a button in an item template in a GridView that uses Command binding to call a method on the ViewModel when the button is clicked. The ViewModel is never released. The Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">

        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                             Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NavigateToOtherPageCommand}"/>

</DataTemplate>
```

If I remove the Command property OR if I comment out the public property (that is never set BTW) in the ViewModel:

```
// public ICommand NavigateToOtherPageCommand { get; private set; }
```

there is no leak. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

One solution I came up with is to put a broadcasting system in place. My ViewModel would register with this singleton in OnNavigatedTo (and unregister in OnNavigatedFrom). The Command binding would now by to the item's context. I would place an ICommand property in the item which upon firing would pass itself to the broadcasting system. Then the broadcasting system would pass the message on to the ViewModel. Feels a bit hacky but I think it will work.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927433/silverlight-datatemplate-memory-leak

Comment: not sure how that related

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to element by name from datatemplate. Try to bind to application-wide resource (singletone/locator pattern) or to use {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}.

Comment: When you say "You can't", do you mean "You're not supposed to" (so as not to create leaks)... because the Command Binding is working...